# как мне удалить второго пользователя GitHub из моего Git

Tags: git, github

Каждый раз, как я добавляю коммиты, мне выдается окошко с выбором пользователя.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что до меня этот ноутбук принадлежал моему другу, который тоже пользовался гитхабом и, судя по всему, ноутбук где-то сохранил его данные.

А теперь вопрос: как мне удалить учетную запись друга, которым он все еще пользуется, так чтобы мне больше не выдавало это окошко выбора пользователя?

Comment: Оно сохраняется в "Панель управления / управлении учетными записями". Точнее путь не подскажу - под рукой нет windows.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-1b5c916a-6a16-889f-8581-fc16e8165ac0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по поводу кэша данных при http-авторизации -
возможно, вам всего лишь надо очистить кэш данных для http-авторизации:

```
$ git credential-cache exit
```

по поводу url

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Пользователь/Web.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

это весьма похоже на url отдалённого хранилища. скорее всего, у вас в локальном хранилище подключено всего одно отдалённое хранилище, и, скорее всего, под псевдонимом origin.

посмотреть его (url) можно, например, такой командой:

```
$ git config remote.origin.url
```

изменить — аналогично:

```
$ git config remote.origin.url новое_значение_url
```

ввобще этот вопрос уже задавался и не раз.

Comment: понятно понятно... извините за повторный вопрос    у меня теперь другая проблемка но думаю этот ответ поможет мне спасибо